# Mysql how to group by after condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use `+=` function while fetch database, but when I use `group by` condition, the final result was not what I want, so please help me to looking on my coding.

I have 3 table, table 1 = `t1`:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ID        | areacode    | landstatus  | pictureid   |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1         | 1           | 0           | 0           |
| 2         | 1           | 0           | 0           |
| 3         | 1           | 4           | 1           |
| 4         | 1           | 4           | 2           |
| 5         | 1           | 4           | 1           |
| 6         | 1           | 2           | 1           |
| 7         | 1           | 4           | 4           |
| 8         | 1           | 1           | 0           |
| 9         | 2           | 0           | 0           |
| 10        | 2           | 4           | 1           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Table 2 = `t2`:

```
+-------+-------------+------------+
| ID    | population  | other      |
+-------+-------------+------------+
| 1     | 10          | 0          |
| 2     | 20          | 0          |
| 3     | 30          | 0          |
| 4     | 40          | 0          |
+-------+-------------+------------+
```

Normally I query the `+-` like this:

Let's say `bid=1`

```
$bid = intval($_GET['bid']);
$queryAP = DB::query("
SELECT t1.*
      , t2.population 
  FROM ".DB::table('t1')." t1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN ".DB::table('t2')." t2 
    ON t1.pictureid = t2.id
 WHERE t1.areacode = '$bid' 
   AND t1.landstatus = 4
");
while($rowAP = DB::fetch($queryAP)) { //search all landstatus == 4
    $totalareaP += $rowAP['population'];
}
```

So the `$totalareaP` output will be `80` when user `query` the `bid=1`. Now my problem is if I would like add a server task (automatic run query when times' up) will update the `$totalareaP` to `t3 where t2.arecode = t3.id` without `$_GET['bid']`.

The Table 3 called : `t3` .

```
+------+------------+-----------+
| ID   | population | timesup   |
+------+------------+-----------+
| 1    | 0          | timestamp |
| 2    | 0          | timestamp |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

I try the coding something like:

```
$queryPPADD = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.population FROM ".DB::table('t1')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('t2')." t2 ON (t1.pictureid = t2.id) GROUP BY t1.areacode WHERE t1.landstatus = 4");
while($rowPPADD = DB::fetch($queryPPADD )) { //search all landstatus == 4
    $totalareaAAP += $rowPPADD ['population'];
}
```

When I print `$totalareaAAP` didn't show any value, I would like to update the `$totalareaAAP` group by `t1.areacode` update into `t3.areacode WHERE t1.areacode = t3.id`

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any way your t1 is connected to your table 2. What  I mean is there is no foreign key in your t2

Comment: `t1.pictureid = t2.id`, I query the `population` from `t2` when `t1.pictureid = t2.id`

Comment: Have you initialized $totalareaAAP?

Comment: hey, Your sql statement looks invalid "Group by Where", plus your += null/undefined values because of the left join.

Comment: Maybe see HAVING - although an aggregate seems nonsensical in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "group by" needs a group-function ("sum" in this case)

```
                                            vvv
$queryPPADD = DB::query("SELECT t1.areacode,sum(t2.population) as population FROM "
 . DB::table('t1') . " t1 LEFT JOIN " . DB::table('t2') 
 . " t2 ON (t1.pictureid = t2.id) GROUP BY t1.areacode WHERE t1.landstatus = 4");
```

(note the `sum(t2.population) as population`)

In the PHP you have to create an array,

```
array(areacode => population)
```

PHP code

```
$result = array();

$queryPPADD = DB::query("SELECT t1.areacode,sum(t2.population) as population FROM "
 . DB::table('t1') . " t1 LEFT JOIN " . DB::table('t2') 
 . " t2 ON (t1.pictureid = t2.id) GROUP BY t1.areacode WHERE t1.landstatus = 4");

while($rowPPADD = DB::fetch($queryPPADD)) {
   $areacode = $rowPPADD ['areacode'];
   $result[$areacode] = $rowPPADD ['population']; // just a =
}
```

Thanks to *sum/group by*, each "areacode" will appear only once in the results. In PHP, the `$result` array has one entry with the total population summed by MySQL for that "areacode".

To display the results

```
foreach ($result as $code => $population) {
   echo "Code $code => $population\n";
}
```

Comment: yes, i need `sum` the `t2.population` when `t1.landstatus = 4` and split by `t1.areacode` .. so the `population` on `areacode = 1` should be `80`, `areacode = 2` should be `0`..

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryPPADD = DB::query("SELECT t1.*,t2.population FROM ".DB::table('t1')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('t2')." t2 ON (t1.pictureid = t2.id) GROUP BY t1.areacode WHERE t1.landstatus = 4");
$totalareaAAP = 0;
while($rowPPADD = DB::fetch($queryPPADD )) { //search all landstatus == 4
    echo $land = $rowPPADD ['landstatus'];// see what it is printing
    echo $pic = $rowPPADD ['pictureid'];// see what it is printing
    echo $pop = $rowPPADD ['population'];// see what it is printing
    echo $totalareaAAP += $rowPPADD ['population'];// see what it is printing
}
```